# Extracting value from nested list

Tags: json, jmespath

The JSON I want to parse looks like this:

```json
{
  "results": [
    [
      {
        "field": "@logStream",
        "value": "i-0d41c4f2b294fae88-messages"
      },
      {
        "field": "@ptr",
        "value": "CmEKJgoiMTI1NzEwNTIwMzE3OkRhdGFJbmdlc3QtZW50ZXJwcmlzZRAHEjUaGAIGPjW1igAAAACsKl4NAAY/k4KwAAAAoiABKIzAjqzoMDC5+ZGs6DA4D0DrEEi4C1DlBxgAEA4YAQ=="
      }
    ]
  ],
  "statistics": {
    "recordsMatched": 94761,
    "recordsScanned": 94761,
    "bytesScanned": 13659575
  },
  "status": "Complete"
}
```

From each sublist in the `results` list, I want the value of `value` for every `field` that equals `@logStream`.
How can this be achieved?

The closest I've been able to come to even getting *anything* that distinguishes `field` values is this:

```
results[].[field==`@logStream`]
```

But that only gives booleans:

```json
[
  [
    true
  ],
  [
    false
  ]
]
```

What I'd like to get is this, or something like it:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "value": "i-0d41c4f2b294fae88-messages"
    }
  ]
]
```

I also tried

```
results[].[field==`@logStream`].value
```

and

```
results[].[field==`@logStream`].[value]
```

but those only gave me `[ null ]` and `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue in your query is the fact that you forgot the question mark `?` in order to make a proper [filter projection `[?someCondition]`](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#filter-projections), and not a [multiselect `.[someAttributeProjectedInAnArray]`](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#multiselect).

The other issue is that you are using a [flatten projection `[]`](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#flatten-projections) on your `results` array [without stopping it](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions), which makes it impossible to do the subsequent filter projection you need on the `field` attribute, where you could have used a `[*]`.

Then, to achieve the selection of the `value` attribute, you can use a [multiselect hash](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#multiselect), this time: `.{value: value}`.

Knowing all this, if you want to achieve exactly the output stated your question, you can use this query:

```
results[*][?field ==`@logStream`].{value: value}
```

Wich would yield:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "value": "i-0d41c4f2b294fae88-messages"
    }
  ]
]
```

---

You can even go further and flatten the list of lists:

```json
results[*][?field ==`@logStream`][].{value: value}
```

Would yield:

```json
[
  {
    "value": "i-0d41c4f2b294fae88-messages"
  }
]
```

Or simplify the multiselect hash in a [list projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#list-and-slice-projections):

```
results[*][?field ==`@logStream`][].value
```

Would yield:

```json
[
  "i-0d41c4f2b294fae88-messages"
]
```

---

Or use alternative syntaxes, by keeping your first flatten projection, stop it with a [pipe expression](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions), then apply your query:

```
results[]|[?field ==`@logStream`].{value: value}
```

Would yield:

```json
[
  {
    "value": "i-0d41c4f2b294fae88-messages"
  }
]
```

And

```
results[]|[?field ==`@logStream`].value
```

Would yield:

```json
[
  "i-0d41c4f2b294fae88-messages"
]
```

Comment: Wow.  Thorough answer.  Thanks.

After I posted my question -- and before I had a chance to come back here and post an answer to my own question -- I went and found me a good JMESPath tutorial, read more carefully the bits I was rusty in, and came up with an answer of my own, which matches *nearly* exactly one of the ones you provided, except that I did the flattening in a different place, but to the same effect:

```results[*][?field==`@logStream`].value[]```

c.f. your:

```results[*][?field==`@logStream`][].value```

Anyway, thanks again.